# 07002 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I am writing some simple Python code to extract data from a CSV file and send it to SQL Server database. But I am getting this 07002 COUNT field incorrect or syntax error. The CSV file has multiple values and if I send just a single row of data, it inserts fine. The issue is with multiple values within the CSV file. Any help is appreciated!

## Here is my code:

```
import_data = []
for csvFile in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    with open(csvFile, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)<br>
        next(reader, None)#This skips the headers.
        import_data = [tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(f)]
```

## Insert data from CSV file to SQL Server

```
cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO dbo.currentobservations(STID,NAME,ST,LAT,LON,YR,MO,DA,HR,MI,TAIR,TDEW,RELH,CHIL,HEAT,WDIR,WSPD,WMAX,PRES,TMAX,TMIN,RAIN) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""", import_data)

#Here is the error message I am getting:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python3\Programs\sqlservermesonetcsv.py", line 40, in <module>
    cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO dbo.currentobservations(STID,NAME,ST,LAT,LON,YR,MO,DA,HR,MI,TAIR,TDEW,RELH,CHIL,HEAT,WDIR,WSPD,WMAX,PRES,TMAX,TMIN,RAIN) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""", import_data)
  File "E:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1671, in executemany
    self.execute(query_string, params, many_mode = True)
  File "E:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1605, in execute
    self.execdirect(query_string)
  File "E:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1631, in execdirect
    check_success(self, ret)
  File "E:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 986, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
  File "E:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 966, in ctrl_err
    raise DatabaseError(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table has 22 columns. It is necessary to hand your ODBC sql server driver rows with exactly 22 elements.

Perhaps some lines in the .csv have 23 or more entries. Then you might try passing `line[:22]` to truncate trailing elements.

If some lines in the .csv turn out to have fewer than 22 entries, you will need to tack suitable default values onto the end of them.